# How to exclude particular values when shuffling a column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, shuffle, sample

I would like to shuffle all the rows in a column unless a row contains one particular value, in which case that row should not be included in the shuffling process (i.e. all rows containing the specified value stay where they are).

Using the iris example below, let's say we want to shuffle all rows of the column `Species` except those rows of `Species` which contain the value `setosa`. How do I do that?

Thanks!

```
library(dplyr) 

set.seed(123)

my_df <- iris %>% 
  mutate(species2 = sample(Species), # shuffles whole column
         # attempted conditional shuffle of non-setosa values (does not work!)
         species3 = sample(nrow(Species != "setosa")))
```

Comment: You could put the setosa and non-setosa species into a separate tables, do the shuffling on the second one and then bind them together.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did consider that idea, but it feels inefficient on the scale I need to work on. The answer below suits the workflow better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try making an external function that does that. `conditional_shuffle` selects cases that don't fit a condition and just uses `sample` on them:

```
library(tidyverse)

conditional_shuffle <- function(vec, condition, seed = 123) {
    set.seed(seed)
    cases2shuffle <- vec != condition
    vec[cases2shuffle] <- sample(vec[cases2shuffle])
    return(vec)
}
iris %>%
    mutate(species2 = conditional_shuffle(Species, "setosa"))
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species   species2
#> 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa     setosa
#> 7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa     setosa
#> 8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa     setosa
#> 11           5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 12           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 13           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1     setosa     setosa
#> 14           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa     setosa
#> 15           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 16           5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa     setosa
#> 17           5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4     setosa     setosa
#> 18           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3     setosa     setosa
#> 19           5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3     setosa     setosa
#> 20           5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3     setosa     setosa
#> 21           5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 22           5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4     setosa     setosa
#> 23           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 24           5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5     setosa     setosa
#> 25           4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 26           5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 27           5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4     setosa     setosa
#> 28           5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 29           5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 31           4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 32           5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4     setosa     setosa
#> 33           5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1     setosa     setosa
#> 34           5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 35           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 36           5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 37           5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 38           4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1     setosa     setosa
#> 39           4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 40           5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 41           5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3     setosa     setosa
#> 42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa     setosa
#> 43           4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 44           5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     setosa     setosa
#> 45           5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4     setosa     setosa
#> 46           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3     setosa     setosa
#> 47           5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 48           4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 49           5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 50           5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     setosa     setosa
#> 51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor versicolor
#> 52           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor  virginica
#> 53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor  virginica
#> 54           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor versicolor
#> 55           6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor  virginica
#> 56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor versicolor
#> 57           6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor versicolor
#> 58           4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor versicolor
#> 59           6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor  virginica
#> 60           5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor versicolor
#> 61           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor  virginica
#> 62           5.9         3.0          4.2         1.5 versicolor  virginica
#> 63           6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor  virginica
#> 64           6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 versicolor versicolor
#> 65           5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor  virginica
#> 66           6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4 versicolor versicolor
#> 67           5.6         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor versicolor
#> 68           5.8         2.7          4.1         1.0 versicolor  virginica
#> 69           6.2         2.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor  virginica
#> 70           5.6         2.5          3.9         1.1 versicolor versicolor
#> 71           5.9         3.2          4.8         1.8 versicolor  virginica
#> 72           6.1         2.8          4.0         1.3 versicolor  virginica
#> 73           6.3         2.5          4.9         1.5 versicolor  virginica
#> 74           6.1         2.8          4.7         1.2 versicolor versicolor
#> 75           6.4         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor versicolor
#> 76           6.6         3.0          4.4         1.4 versicolor  virginica
#> 77           6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor  virginica
#> 78           6.7         3.0          5.0         1.7 versicolor versicolor
#> 79           6.0         2.9          4.5         1.5 versicolor versicolor
#> 80           5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 versicolor versicolor
#> 81           5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor  virginica
#> 82           5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor  virginica
#> 83           5.8         2.7          3.9         1.2 versicolor  virginica
#> 84           6.0         2.7          5.1         1.6 versicolor  virginica
#> 85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor  virginica
#> 86           6.0         3.4          4.5         1.6 versicolor versicolor
#> 87           6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 versicolor  virginica
#> 88           6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 versicolor versicolor
#> 89           5.6         3.0          4.1         1.3 versicolor versicolor
#> 90           5.5         2.5          4.0         1.3 versicolor versicolor
#> 91           5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 versicolor versicolor
#> 92           6.1         3.0          4.6         1.4 versicolor versicolor
#> 93           5.8         2.6          4.0         1.2 versicolor versicolor
#> 94           5.0         2.3          3.3         1.0 versicolor versicolor
#> 95           5.6         2.7          4.2         1.3 versicolor versicolor
#> 96           5.7         3.0          4.2         1.2 versicolor  virginica
#> 97           5.7         2.9          4.2         1.3 versicolor  virginica
#> 98           6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor  virginica
#> 99           5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor versicolor
#> 100          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor  virginica
#> 101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica  virginica
#> 102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica versicolor
#> 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica  virginica
#> 104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8  virginica  virginica
#> 105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2  virginica versicolor
#> 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica versicolor
#> 107          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica versicolor
#> 108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8  virginica  virginica
#> 109          6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8  virginica  virginica
#> 110          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5  virginica versicolor
#> 111          6.5         3.2          5.1         2.0  virginica  virginica
#> 112          6.4         2.7          5.3         1.9  virginica versicolor
#> 113          6.8         3.0          5.5         2.1  virginica versicolor
#> 114          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0  virginica versicolor
#> 115          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4  virginica  virginica
#> 116          6.4         3.2          5.3         2.3  virginica versicolor
#> 117          6.5         3.0          5.5         1.8  virginica  virginica
#> 118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica  virginica
#> 119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3  virginica versicolor
#> 120          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5  virginica  virginica
#> 121          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3  virginica versicolor
#> 122          5.6         2.8          4.9         2.0  virginica  virginica
#> 123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica versicolor
#> 124          6.3         2.7          4.9         1.8  virginica  virginica
#> 125          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1  virginica  virginica
#> 126          7.2         3.2          6.0         1.8  virginica  virginica
#> 127          6.2         2.8          4.8         1.8  virginica  virginica
#> 128          6.1         3.0          4.9         1.8  virginica versicolor
#> 129          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1  virginica  virginica
#> 130          7.2         3.0          5.8         1.6  virginica versicolor
#> 131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica  virginica
#> 132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica versicolor
#> 133          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.2  virginica versicolor
#> 134          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5  virginica versicolor
#> 135          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4  virginica  virginica
#> 136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica  virginica
#> 137          6.3         3.4          5.6         2.4  virginica  virginica
#> 138          6.4         3.1          5.5         1.8  virginica  virginica
#> 139          6.0         3.0          4.8         1.8  virginica versicolor
#> 140          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1  virginica versicolor
#> 141          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4  virginica  virginica
#> 142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3  virginica versicolor
#> 143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica  virginica
#> 144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3  virginica versicolor
#> 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5  virginica versicolor
#> 146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3  virginica versicolor
#> 147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9  virginica  virginica
#> 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0  virginica versicolor
#> 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica  virginica
#> 150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica versicolor
```